# Antivirus, Firewall and etc

Tags: windows-7, firewall, anti-virus

I've been using Panda for some years now, and in about a month my Panda Internet Security license is going to expire, and I am not going to renew it.

I do not know much about AVs and firewalls and the like, but it seems to me that PandaIS has both of these. I think the Av in itself blocks Viruses and Malware and the firewall blocks intrusion attempts and the like.

My questions are: Does a free AV have all of this as well? Do I have to use a free AV combined with the windows firewall? If so, how is the windows firewall compared to AV firewalls (such as Panda's)? If not, are there any free firewall software (much like the free AV software)?

Thank you!

Comment: Why the down vote? The question is well structured and does not ask for a subjective answer.

Comment: I don't quite understand why the question was closed. Can anyone enlighten me? You "expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise", but I don't see why this question doesn't fit those parameters. Also, the answer given fitted the parameters, and was not subjective (at least I'd think so). The comments it spawned are the ones that are off-topic and "solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion." Can anyone help me improve the question so that it is reopened?

Comment: When I ask "how is the windows firewall compared to AV firewalls?", I do not mean to get "it is better/worse" answers. I expect to get some "based on real world/removal/prevention tests, it performed better/same/worse", or "it performs faster/slower on average tests", or the like. But still, I get it why it's been closed. Isn't there some way to improve it so that it gets reopened?

Comment: I really don't understand why no one can help me improve the question so that it gets reopened (perhaps it is beyond help). Still, I'd like to say I got Comodo firewall and Avast! free AV installed. I'll still check out MSE as suggested by @stan31337

Answer (score 2):

Get [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/security-essentials-download). I've tried KIS and Avast before, but finally stopped on this one, and used it for a year before gaining immunity by changing Windows to Linux :)

**Does a free AV have all of this as well?**

Security Essentials is actually very good on this one.

**Do I have to use a free AV combined with the windows firewall?**

Security Essentials enables the builtin firewall and uses it.

Besides all that - you must ensure that automatic updates are turned on. Getting your system patched and fixed is the most important thing to become more secure, then goes AV+Firewall.

Comment: Does its firewall do a good job blocking intrusion attempts? I ask this because when I am using µTorrent, Panda often tells me he blocked intrusion attempts.

Comment: you are not gaining immunity by changing to Linux - it is susceptible to viruses too, its just not as big of a target right now. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_malware ... There are Linux antivirus, and i would suggest you get one. :)

Comment: Intrusion attempt in most cases is an automated script that scans your system for vulnerabilities, therefore keeping your system up to date is the main thing. Firewall blocks all incoming ports, except for those that need to be opened (uTorrent). So keep your OS and uTorrent up to date, firewall will handle the rest...

Comment: @caesay Of course "immunity" is a high word, but still... How much harm a virus can do if it's not running under root?

Comment: @stan31337: I'm assuming the damage would be similar to how much damage something could do if it were not elevated in windows 7.